# PHP and A id in URL?

Tags: php, html, url, variables, hyperlink

In part of a web page, I currently link to a part of the webpage using . In other words, I link to something like:

```
<a href="index.php#blog">Link 1</a>
```

However, on that same link I want to include a PHP variable, which would normally look like

```
<a href="index.php?id=1">Link 2</a>
```

Combining the two in either order just makes the page refresh, neither scrolling properly or taking the php variable. How can I use the two simultaneously?

Comment: try `index.php?id=1#blog` and see if it works

Comment: If it's the same page you should be able to just use `<a href="#blog">...</a>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can concatenate the two together, just put the hash last because that is not sent to the webserver (it will be used by the browser to jump to a certain part of the page):

```
<a href="index.php?id=1#blog">Link 1</a>
```

Comment: +1, although if you are on the same page, you really should just use `href='#blog'`

Answer (score 1):

When you're on the same page as the URL in your anchor, regardless of #'s value (It's called the "fragment"), the page won't even refresh, it will scroll up in hope to find an anchor that has the fitting name for the fragment

The URL fragment (everything behind # at the end of an URL) is a client-side thing, PHP won't be able to do anything with it